# Prove a regular surface without umbilical points is minimal iff its shape operator is" almost an isometry"

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, minimal-surfaces

> Let $M$ be a regular surface without umbilical points. Prove $M$ is
>   minimal iff its  Gauss map $\mathrm N$ satisfies for all $p\in M$ and
>   $w_1,w_2\in \mathrm T_pM$ the equality $$ \left\langle \mathrm
>  d_p\mathrm N w_1,\mathrm d_p\mathrm Nw_2 \right\rangle_{\mathrm Np} =
>  \lambda (p) \left\langle  w_1,w_2\right\rangle_p $$ for some
>   $\lambda(p)\neq 0$ depending on $p$ only.

**My attmept.** By self adjointness of the shape operator
 $$ \left\langle \mathrm
 d_p\mathrm N w_1,\mathrm d_p\mathrm Nw_2 \right\rangle_{\mathrm Np} = 
 \left\langle \mathrm
 (\mathrm d_p\mathrm N)^2 w_1,w_2 \right\rangle_p.$$
Now, $$ \left\langle \mathrm
 (\mathrm d_p\mathrm N)^2 w_1,w_2 \right\rangle_p=\lambda (p) \left\langle  w_1,w_2\right\rangle_p$$ for all $w_1,w_2$ iff $(\mathrm d_p\mathrm N)^2=\lambda (p)I$ iff $k_1^2=k_2^2=\lambda(p)$.

Under the assumption $M$ has no umbilical points, the principal curvatures are distinct, so this is equivalent to $k_1=-k_2$.

---

Is my solution correct? I'm looking at another student's solution and see it's a long computation in terms of bases of tangent spaces and hope it's not necessary.

Comment: Hi, i know this question is old but i have a question: How does the equality $(d_pN)^2=\lambda(p)$ holds? As far as i understand the left side is a vector and the right side is a number.

Comment: Look at the RHS more closely: there's an $I$ there.